# Understanding the JTAG pinout

Tags: jtag

I need to program an old board on which I have very little information. On this board there is an old Xilinx FPGA and some memory chip, on one side there is a JTAG connector from which you think it is possible to read the old FW and load the new one.

The problem is that I don't know the pinout of the JTAG connector, from what I see it is a connector with only 6 pins in line. I think 99% of them are in the classic TMS-TDI-TDO-TCK-GND-VDD order, but I'm not sure.

Is there a way to figure out the pinout? For example, finding GND is easy, but for others are there any features I can check? I don't know, maybe some of them have to be an open circuit to ground, or on some I have to measure a specific impedance, or something like that....

If I do some connection tests trying various possible pinouts and I get the pinout wrong, can I damage the board or the chip?

Comment: Vcc and GND you can find with a multimeter. For the rest, can you trace them to whatever IC you are trying to communicate with?

Comment: By using a "good quality" programmer, you can safely test your 99% hyphothesis. If you hit the 1% jackpot, i would start tracing. If not possible: 4 Lines gives 24 combinations to try.... might take an hour but whatever.